# Extracting a specific number from a string with many numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

Unfortunately I couldn't find an answer to this specific issue. I have a string:

`task[orders_attributes][4][line_items_attributes][2][id]`

I know I could just use `.match(/\d+/)` if there was only one number, but how do I extract only the `2` from this?

The number will be in range from 0 to 9999999999999, so the string length of the number needs to be taken into account, and the first number of the string (the one after `orders_attributes`) will also be dynamic.  Text and brackets are static.

Comment: Could you please add sample input and expected output to your question

Comment: Sample input is the string above, `task[orders_attributes][4][line_items_attributes][2][id]`, Output from this would be `2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `/\d+/g` regex pattern. This will return all numbers to an array.

```js
let str = "task[orders_attributes][4][line_items_attributes][2][id]";
let pattern = /\d+/g;
let matches = str.match(pattern);
 
console.log(matches[1]); //Use matches[1] to get the second number.
```

Comment: I didn't know I could add that `[1]` to the end of the match pattern.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like below

```js
let str = "task[orders_attributes][45][line_items_attributes][23][id]";
let pat = /(\[\d+\])/g;
let matches = str.match(pat);
 
console.log(matches[1]); //Use matches[1] to get the second number.
```